# How to create constraint for Zk upload button

Tags: java, zk

i have to validate no empty constraint for upload button how to do that ?

this is upload button tag in Zul

```
<cell>
  <button label="Upload Id Proof"  id="uploadId"  upload="true, maxsize=50"/>
 </cell>
```

Here i have to validate no empty constrain for above upload in java or zul itself like textbox.
please give any suggestion.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [This demo](https://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/file_handling/file_upload) should give you the basics of what you need. It isn't a constraint but does show how to validate input.

Comment: its not show any alerts. i want validations in java

Comment: You need to move the `CDATA` code to your view model as follows:

zul code:<code>
    `<button label="Upload Id Proof"  id="uploadId"  upload="true, maxsize=50" onUpload="@command('fileUploaded', media=event.getMedia())" />`

view model:
   ` @Command
    public void fileUploaded(@BindingParam("media") Media media) {
        // process your media
    }`